# LinkedIn embedded widget fails accessibility audit

Tags: iframe, accessibility, linkedin-api, wcag2.0

We've implemented a LinkedIn Company Insider widget on our site, but the embedded markup is failing accessibility tests.

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/CompanyInsider" data-id="XXXXX" data-modules="innetwork,newhires,jobchanges" data-width="400"></script>
```

When the module is rendered into the page, it includes two iframes (one within the other) but neither iframe is properly labelled with a title to describe its contents to assistive technology users.

Here's the rendered markup from one as an example:

`<iframe id="li_xxx" name="li_xxx" src="javascript: void(0);" style="visibility: visible; width: 633px; height: 285px; background: transparent;" true"="" framspacing="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

Since the code is embedded at runtime I can't modify the title attribute manually - are there any methods or parameters to properly label the iframe? I'd prefer not to have to use jQuery to inject it.

The WCAG documentation requires all frames/iframes to provide a descriptive title attribute to identify the purpose of the iframe: http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H64.html